# Cannot convert value of type '(_, _) -> ()' to expected argument type 'UserProfile.Completion' with Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm using FacebookCore (I think the problem is there), and I get the error "Cannot convert value of type `(_, _) -> ()` to expected argument type `UserProfile.Completion`"when I try to compile.

The error appears in the first line, and the code is

```
UserProfile.loadCurrent() { (userProfile, error) in
    guard let userProfile = userProfile else {
        completion(profile: nil, error: Error(domain: "FacebookLoginManager", code: 333, userInfo: ["description" : "Error al obtener el perfil del usuario"]))
        return
    }
    completion(profile: userProfile, error: error)
}
```

`UserProfile.Completion` code is

```
public typealias Completion = (FetchResult) -> Void
```

And `FetchResult` code is

```
extension UserProfile.FetchResult {
    internal init(sdkProfile: FBSDKProfile?, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            self = .failed(error)
        } else if let sdkProfile = sdkProfile {
            let profile = UserProfile(sdkProfile: sdkProfile)
            self = .success(profile)
        } else {      
            let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 42, userInfo: nil)
            self = .failed(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the FacebookCore documentation, it looks like the completion closure of `loadCurrent()` is of type `FetchResult` which is an enum:

`(FetchResult) -> Void`

and not:

`(UserProfile?,Error?) -> Void`

You should change it like so:

```
UserProfile.loadCurrent() { (fetchResult) in

    UserProfile.loadCurrent { (fetchResult) in

        switch fetchResult {
        case .success(let userProfile):
            completion(profile: userProfile, error: nil)
        case .failed(let error):
            completion(profile: nil, error: Error(domain: "FacebookLoginManager", code: 333, userInfo: ["description" : "Error al obtener el perfil del usuario"]))
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: FetchRsult is initialize in UserProfile.FetchResult.swift, in the pod FacebookCore.

`public enum FetchResult{
 case success(UserProfile)
case failed(Error)}`

Comment: @CarlosGutiérrez After having checked the FacebookCore doc, this should be a more accurate answer!